# How to add support for encoding Cp866ukr in Android

Tags: java, android, encoding, character-encoding, cp866

How can I add support for *Cp866ukr* (for Ukrainian language) encoding in my Android application? I need to extend [Charset](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) class. Is there any open-source implementation of this charset for Java (like [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/sun/nio/cs/IBM866.java) for default *Cp866*)?